# python google recognize only work on portuguese dont work on english

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use google speech_recognition but only works when i use audio files on portuguese, if i use some audio on english gives me that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deabr_000\Downloads\stt.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US"))
  File "C:\Users\deabr_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

the full code is here:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with  sr.WavFile('C:/Users/deabr_000/Downloads/something_inside.wav') as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

print(r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US"))
```

I'm using songs because I need to get the lyrics to do something, I have success with pt-br songs but with any song with another language just dont work

I dont know what the problem is cause with songs that I download from youtube and convert into wav dont work (if the song is pt-br work), but with that audio files works (https://github.com/realpython/python-speech-recognition/tree/master/audio_files)

what the heck can I do?

Comment: Brazilian music is much more pleasant even for google cloud